# Ошибка при подключении к MySQL c помощью jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysqlconnector

Подключаюсь к MySQL с помощью драйвера mysql-connector-8.0.19.jar (взятый из официального установщика). Используя встроенный "подключатор классов" (не знаю, как это по-человечески назвать) в Intellij IDEA. В коде это:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

и

```
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/vegetablewarehouse", "root", "12345");
```

В ответ получаю такую ошибку:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/vegetablewarehouse
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Весь код:

```
public class DBHandler {
    public static Connection dbConnection;

    public Connection getDbConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("1");
        dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306", "root", "12345");
        System.out.println("3");
        return dbConnection;
    }

    public ResultSet getUser(User user) {
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        System.out.println("2");
        String select = "SELECT * FROM " + DBConstant.USER_TABLE + " WHERE " + DBConstant.USER_EMAIL
                + "=? AND " + DBConstant.USER_PASSWORD + "=?"; //Строка запроса

        try{
            PreparedStatement pst = getDbConnection().prepareStatement(select);
            pst.setString(1, user.getEmail());
            pst.setString(2, user.getPassword());
            System.out.println("3");
            resultSet = pst.executeQuery();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    return resultSet;
    }
```

Выводит 1 и 2.

Comment: Проверьте настройки подключения, например через программу `dbeaver`.
Если сможете подключиться, значит ошибка в том, что jar файл не может найти, если не сможет, значит настройки неверно указали.

Comment: Все вроде верно, покажите полный код, есть ощущение, что вы там что-то напутали с ловлей `Exception` во время `Class.forName()`

Comment: Проблема решилась сама собой, судя по всему нужно было просто перезагрузить ПК.